# Can I do max filter on a sub_blocks with matlab

Tags: matlab

For example, I have a 4x4 matrix, I want to split the max into 2x2 sub_regions. and do max on the sub_region.

```
 1,  2,  3,  4
 5,  6,  7,  8
 9, 10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15, 16
\|/
 6,  6,  8,  8
 6,  6,  8,  8
14, 14, 16, 16
14, 14, 16, 16
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this suit your need?

(Assuming your data is in a matrix called `M`)

```
>> cellfun(@(x) max(x(:)), mat2cell(M, [2 2], [2 2]))

ans =

     6     8
    14    16
```

**EDIT:**

You could also include [kron](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) to achieve your desired output:

```
>> kron(cellfun(@(x) max(x(:)), mat2cell(M, [2 2], [2 2])), ones(2))

ans =

     6     6     8     8
     6     6     8     8
    14    14    16    16
    14    14    16    16
```

Comment: Yes, But I need to apply `expand` function to get the same size with the original matrix

Comment: Sure, `expand` would be better than `kron`! :)

Answer (score 2):

[`colfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) will get the job done:

```
>> M = 2; N = 2;
>> B = colfilt(A,[M N],'distinct',@(x)repmat(max(x),[M*N 1]))

B =

     6     6     8     8
     6     6     8     8
    14    14    16    16
    14    14    16    16
```

The key is to use the `'distinct'` block type option.  Test data: `A = reshape(1:16,4,4).'`.

---

You can also use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) if you prefer:

```
B = blockproc(A,[M N],@(b) repmat(max(b.data(:)),[M N]))
```

OR

```
B = kron(blockproc(A,[M N],@(b) max(b.data(:))),ones(M,N))
```

Note: Image Processing Toolbox required for both.